# Long to short pathnames without p/invoke

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, .net

Does anyone know how to convert long to short pathnames in .net 3.5 without p/invoke?  I can do it with p/invoke if I have to, but I'd rather not.

Comment: There's no such thing as C# 3.5 (or VB 3.5). There's .NET 3.5, C# 3.0 and VB 9.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... I'm assuming you understood what I was talking about though... 

I guess I was trying to make the point that it doesn't matter to me whether responses are in C# or VB and that .I am coding against .NET 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that P/Invoke is the only way.